# Create simplest typescript definition file possible

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.7

I am trying to use the [Salesforce JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK) in a Typescript project.

It has a file called [canvas-all.js](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK/blob/master/js/canvas-all.js).  That has a variable called `Sfdc`.

We have some javascript that uses this successfully.  All it needs to do to use it is add this to the `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./plugins/canvas-sdk/js/canvas-all.js"></script>
```

But Typescript does not know about it from that.  (Says `Cannot find name Sfdc`)

I tried to just import it like this:

```
import * as canvas from '../plugins/canvas-sdk/js/canvas-all';
```

But that gives the error:

> Cannot find module '../plugins/canvas-sdk/js/canvas-all'.

I am thinking I need a `.d.ts` for this, but I can't find one, and I am not succeeding in trying to make one.

I have looked at this aricle: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/01/complex-typescript-definitions-made-easy/ but it does not seem to help.

Step 2 in that article is for those that just want Typescript to be unblocked (my scenario).  But all it says is `declare var amazingToolkit: any`  (It does not have any context on where to put it or how to get it recognized by typescript in the file you need to use it.)

I don't need intelisense.  I just want `Sfdc` to be seen as an `any` so that the Typescript will compile when I do something like this:

```
Sfdc.canvas.client.refreshSignedRequest( .....
```

So here is my question:

**How can I make the simplest Typescript Definition file (`.d.ts`) possible for a JavaScript file with a bunch of functions?**

**And how do I get it "connected" to the JavaScript (`canvas-all.js`) file (that has no modules) and imported into my Typescript (`myApplicationFile.ts`) file?**

Answer (score 3):

OK, so this is what worked.  I made a file called `canvas-all.d.ts` and put this in it:

```
declare var Sfdc: any;
```

After a re-build the errors went away.  I had tried this before, but without a full rebuild.  Visual Studio did not see it without the rebuild.

Comment: I have the same problem. but just creating the file didn't help me. do you import the Sfdc in any place in your code?